# Having issue in uploading images to uploads directory

Tags: wordpress

I am having a problem while uploading images in wordpress working on xampp i am using mac it shows The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2019/04.

Comment: Please check folder permission. or check in console error.

Comment: permissions are at read and write

Comment: where to upload image ? what is image extension type .?

Comment: uploads folder in wp-content and the extension is .jpg

Comment: using wp-admin dashboard or costume code .?

Comment: can you please share your code.

Comment: using wp-admin dashboard

Comment: after ajax request what is return in ajax response .?

Comment: {"success":false,"data":{"message":"The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/04.","filename":"profile.jpg"}}

Comment: Try this

$ sudo chown -R _www uploads/
$ sudo chmod -R g+w uploads/

Comment: It says illegal username

Comment: 100% folder access permissions issue.

Comment: but it is already at read and write than what should i do than

Comment: wp-content folder required 755 permission.

Comment: you must me valid login user permission of the folder. try with root user.

Comment: i am logged in as admin and the folder has 755 permissions